# flatten list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to flatten the list:

```
exampleArray = [[[151.68694121866872]], 
                [[101.59534468349297]], 
                [[72.16055999176308]]]
```

to:

```
[151.68694121866872, 101.59534468349297, 72.16055999176308]
```

Right now I am doing this:

```
resultArray= list(chain.from_iterable(list(chain.from_iterable(exampleArray))))
```

Even though it works I wanted to know if there's a better way.

Comment: what is `chain.from_iterable()` ?

Comment: It is [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Comment: I guess then just `list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(lis)))` is enough, no need of that `list()` call.
`

Comment: is it always just a list containing single element (nested) sublists?

Comment: This is very close: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/63011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
result = [x[0][0] for x in exampleArray]
```

Comment: Very good specific example. Not the best general one though, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [6]: from itertools import chain

In [7]: lis=[[[151.68694121866872]], [[101.59534468349297]], [[72.16055999176308]]]

In [8]: list(chain(*(chain(*lis))))

Out[8]: [151.68694121866872, 101.59534468349297, 72.16055999176308]
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a better way, this is the most recommended way. See [official recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)
```

Comment: thanks just wanted to see if there was will remove the extra list I added to the code

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the `itertools.chain` object (an iterable) into a list:

```
resultArray= list(chain.from_iterable(list(chain.from_iterable(exampleArray))))
# could be rewritten as
resultArray= list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(exampleArray)))
```

.

You could write a deepness function using recursion:

```
def deep_chain_from_iterable(it, n):
    if n == 0:
        return list(it)
    else:
        return deep_chain_from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(it),n-1)

deep_chain_from_iterable(exampleArray, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixed level of depth (as in example) you can just sum enough times:

```
sum(sum(listoflistsoflists, []), [])
```